# CREATE_FAILED ElasticLoadBalancer The requested Availability Zone us-east-1c is constrained and cannot be used together with us-east-1a

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm using the US East (N. Virginia) sample templates from http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-sample-templates.html

and launching the `AWS CloudFormation Sample Template AutoScalingKeepAtNSample` however I keep getting this error:

```
CREATE_FAILED   AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer ElasticLoadBalancer 
The requested Availability Zone us-east-1c is constrained and cannot be used 
together with us-east-1a. Please retry your request by not choosing us-east-1c 
and us-east-1a together.
```

The AWS Dashboard reports I'm in the `US East (N. Virginia)` region.

Any suggestions why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [**Availability Zones**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-regions-availability-zones.html#concepts-regions-availability-zones) section of the Regions and Availability Zones documentation,

> As Availability Zones grow over time, our ability to expand them can become constrained. If this happens, we might restrict you from launching an instance in a constrained Availability Zone unless you already have an instance in that Availability Zone. Eventually, we might also remove the constrained Availability Zone from the list of Availability Zones for new customers. Therefore, your account might have a different number of available Availability Zones in a region than another account.

To workaround this issue, you will have follow the error's advice, and change the list of availability zones provided to your ELB resource.

To accomplish this in a CloudFormation template, you may have to add an input [Parameter](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html) to your template to manually provide a List of Availability Zones (using the [`List<AWS::EC2::AvailabilityZone::Name>`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html#aws-specific-parameter-types) Type) rather than relying on the [`Fn::GetAZs`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-getavailabilityzones.html) function, which returns all Availability Zones.

Comment: This feels really awkward, especially because there doesn't seem to be a way to provide a default template parameter that matches the region the user is launching the cloudformation stack in.  Is there any way to write a custom Fn::GetAvailableAzs function that would get the *available* Azs for that account in that region?

Comment: @tleyden in general, you can write arbitrary provisioning logic in CloudFormation templates using [Custom Resources](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html); however to specifically work around constrained-AZ errors, I don't think any AWS API lists which AZs are constrained, so even with a Custom Resource an automated workaround may not be possible. The only option I can think of would be to file a support request with AWS and ask them to add a new API listing constrained zones or modify `GetAvailableAZs` to filter constrained zones.